# Timer for applying settings WSO2 API-manager

Tags: timer, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have used the WSO2 API manager in my company.
When I change the settings of the available methods (scopes) or the available authorisation methods (application level security), the application of these settings takes up to 15 minutes (I tested the work of the methods through postman).
This is a lot for running tests. Is it possible to reduce the time of applying the settings?

Comment: I followed Pubci's recommendation and it helped the first time. However, after a while, the settings were applied again after 15 minutes.
I disabled the cache altogether, but it didn't help the as well. Settings are applied quickly only the first time after restarting WSO2. 
Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it is 15 minutes (900 seconds). You can change the value in the deployment.toml

```
[apim.cache.resource]
enable = true
expiry_time = "900s"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't have it in deployment.toml, but I add it, and it looks like it works.